# How to set an image from Embedded resource using XAML in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, embedded-resource

When setting an image source in code and pointing towards an embedded image in a specific folder in the PCL project ('Images' in this instance) I would do this:

```
backgroundImg.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Myapp.Images." + imageName + ".jpg");
```

Is there a way to do this in XAML?

Answer (score 16):

@Code Pope is correct in his answer, but you also need to add an "ImageResourceExtension" as noted in the comments by @Gerald Versluis.

To do that just create a new file (class) "ImageResourceExtension.cs" like this:

```
using System;  
using System.Reflection;  
using Xamarin.Forms;  
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ImageResourceExtension 
{
    [ContentProperty (nameof(Source))]
    class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Source == null) 
            {
                return null;
            }

            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source, typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
            return imageSource;
        }
    } 
}
```

Then add `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageResourceExtension"` to your xaml file like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageResourceExtension"
         ...
```

Now you can access an embedded resource using xaml code like this:

```
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource MyProject.Resources.Images.Logo.png}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource YourMobileAppName.YouImageName.jpg}" />
```

For more info, read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#using-xaml)

Comment: I had tried this before but I get the error 'Type ImageResource not found in xmlns clr-namespace' and it won't build.

Comment: And have inserted your app name as prefix to the image?

Comment: have tried {local:ImageResource MyApp.Images.testImg.jpg} and also {local:ImageResource MyApp.testImg.jpg}

Comment: @DarkW1nter you will have to implement the extension that can be found on the page and import it into the `local` namespace in the root of your page. You will still need to make adjustments to make it take in dynamic image filenames probably though

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by adding the ImageSource as an object in my View Model

```
public object ImageSource { get; set; }
```

Then populating the View Model as follows:

```
ImageSource = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromResource("ProjectName.Resources.Images.Image1.png", typeof(WalkthroughViewModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly),
```

In the XAML, I simply referenced it as I would any other binding.

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
```

I am aware that the question doesn't necessarily use/require model-binding as you would with MVVM but I stumbled upon the answer provided [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090850/how-to-set-an-image-from-embedded-resource-using-xaml-in-xamarin-forms/61705507#61705507) which helped me figure out the MVVM approach for anyone else who finds it useful. My particular use-case was for a [CarouselView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/populate-data) where I figured an embedded set of images would be useful.

Answer (score -2):

you can set image from xaml like `<Image Source="imageName" Aspect="AspectFit" />`
Make sure your image available in iOS Resources and in Android Resources -> drawable

Comment: He asked specifically do retrieve the image from the shared project